# Material design input with bootstrap-4

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, material-design, vue.js, bootstrap-4

I am creating a vue webapp and using [bootstrap-4](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/) as CSS framework. I want to have input fields like [material design](https://material.google.com/components/text-fields.html#text-fields-required-fields), But bootstrap have only older design of [input fields](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/input-group/) with border on all sides and no floating label.

What can be best way to get this done?

Comment: You can try with the custom CSS, I have used in some of my projects, https://jsfiddle.net/sanjeevks121/t3ntexff/

Comment: Did you try including `materialize js` and `css`, along with `bootstrap`?

Answer (score 1):

You should overwrite standard Bootstrap rules with one you need - very simple process.

There are Bootstrap Material, but I think it's for version 3

http://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/bootstrap-elements.html

But you can take rules from here, for partial that you need, and paste it to your custom CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You may customize what resources you want from bootstrap, doing it you might not have incompatibility with 2 frameworks breaking css  each other...

http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

you may try getting resources like grids... something that will not break material design...

I already did it.

Comment: how will this help? one thing I am using bootstrap4, second bootstrap does not even have material design input fields with floating label, etc.

Comment: try getting a custom css from codepen.io, use this link to see the best one

Comment: http://codepen.io/search/pens?q=floating%20label&limit=all&order=popularity&depth=everything&show_forks=false