# Materialize inside Vue.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, materialize

I am new with Vue.js and I want to make my project with Materialize. I try a lot of plugins like: vue-materialize (https://github.com/paulpflug/vue-materialize), vue-material-components(https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-material-components) and didn't work. I also tried to add jQuery plugin to webpack and I don't have any solution:

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jquery: 'jquery',
    'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery'
}),
```

Now I am trying to make work a input select field. How can I make this work?

Comment: Have a look at this question on [material input](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40888352/1610034) and [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sanjeevks121/t3ntexff/).

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Vue-Material](https://github.com/vuematerial/vue-material) to materialize your Vue project. Following are the steps that you need to follow:

1. Install vuematerial `$ npm install --save vue-material`
2. Import vuematerial to your main.js `import VueMaterial from 'vue-material'` `import 'vue-material/dist/vue-material.css'`
3. Start using vuematerial in your project `Vue.use(VueMaterial)`

A sample `main.js` file should look something like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueMaterial from 'vue-material'
import 'vue-material/dist/vue-material.css';
import App from './App';
import router from './router';

Vue.use(VueMaterial)
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App },
});
```

You will now be able to use vuematerial components inside your template.

Answer (score 5):

Here is my setup to use Materialize with [Vue Webpack template](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack):

**build/webpack.base.conf.js**

```
var webpack = require('webpack')
module.exports =
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      ...
      'jquery': 'materialize-css/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js'
    }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
        ...
        options: {
          limit: 10000
  ....
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jquery: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery',
      'window.$': 'jquery',
      'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
    })
  ]
}
```

**index.html**

```
<head>
  ...
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

**package.json**

```
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "materialize-css": "^0.98.2",
  ...
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jquery": "^2.0.43", // ==> if using typescript
```

**src/main.js**

```
import 'materialize-css'
import 'materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.css'
```

So, for a "input select field" like below:

```
<div class="input-field" ref="myInput">
  <select>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
  </select>
  <label>Materialize Select</label>
</div>
```

...you could put this code in your `mounted` lifecycle hook:

```
mounted() {
  $(this.$refs.myInput).material_select()
```

Answer (score -4):

`Vue.js` given link by you reffers `Materializecss` and both are look same. Here I have added fully working code with `drop down button`.

You can just copy and paste following code to a text file and save it as a .html file (ex: `name.html`). You can edit this code by adding relevant code in between the comment `<!--your code start-->`  and `<!--your code end-->`.

Click the `Run code Snippet` button below to test online and you can see `DROP ME!` button. Once you click it you can see how drop down works.

More details refer [materializecss](http://materializecss.com/dropdown.html) which is more user friendly than the link you have given.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Slider</title>
        <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.3/css/materialize.min.css">
        <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <!--your code start-->
        
              <!-- Dropdown Trigger -->
              <a class='dropdown-button btn' href='#' data-activates='dropdown1'>Drop Me!</a>

              <!-- Dropdown Structure -->
              <ul id='dropdown1' class='dropdown-content'>
                <li><a href="#!">one</a></li>
                <li><a href="#!">two</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#!">three</a></li>
              </ul>      
      
        <!--your code end-->

        <!--Import jQuery before materialize.js-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.3/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
     
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: where is vue in example? it's part of main question

Comment: @oswaldo Thank you for the comment. Yes, you are right. But the provided link contains 'Materializecss'. Therefore I clearly mentioned that I am referring Materializecss since sometimes it may be helpful him or others users. Have a nice day. :)